# Using Facebook SDK to extract you friends info (more than just name or ID)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

i am using FB SDK v.3.2.3 , and i'm trying to retrieve the events that my friends are going to. So far, my code can retrieve the list of friends who are using my app. The documentation on FB tells the event can be pulled out by using "me/events", but since i want my friend's event to be pulled, i used "me/friends/event" or "me/friends?fields=event", but it still does not work. Someone has an idea about it?  Below is my code --

```
<pre>
  require_once('facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'xxx',
    'secret' => 'xxx'
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);

  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

     if($user_id) {
         try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($user_profile);
        echo "</pre>";

          $dost = $facebook->api('/me/friends','GET');

            foreach ($dost as $friend) {
          echo "<pre>";
         print_r($friend);
         echo "</pre>";
       }

        echo '<br><a href=' . $facebook->destroySession() . '>Logout</a>';

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) { }   

    } else {

    $params = array(
        'scope' => 'public_profile, user_friends, email',
        'redirect_url' => 'http://xxxxx.com',
        'auto_logout_link' => 'true',
        'show_faces' => 'true'

       );
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }
```

Comment: Use /me/events using the access token of the friend or use /{userid}/events

Comment: Most likely the access token are not allowed to see them. Try with the friends access token

Comment: You have to store the access token when the user logs in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
//...
$dost = $facebook->api('/me/friends','GET');

foreach ($dost["data"] as $value) {  
   $friend_id = $value['id'];
   $events = $facebook->api('/'.$friend_id.'/events'); 
   print_r($events);    
}
//...
```

Comment: This returns a blank set of array.. This is the output ---- Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
        )

)----- any clues brother? (And yes, my friends do have events in their schedule)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook changed the privacy policy for friends - your friends also need to give permission to your app

Comment: Yes, i am aware of that, and i infact have asked for permission in my code above :) The only problem is that i cannot extract my friends event list from the code!